# After copy the website to a local server, "buy", "buy in one click" buttons don't work

Tags: javascript, apache, opencart

I have store on Opencart CMS, ive just CEO, but now would like to learn how does it works:). For this I copy it to local webserver (macos 10.10.3, Apache/2.4.10, mysql, php5.5). On the local webserver the site opens, you can click on links - it works. But I have problems with "buy" buttons and some others links that open popup windows (buy in credit, buy in one click) - it doesnt work. What can i do to make it works?

When I open product page, in Chrome console there are this errors:

```
carouFredSel: No element found for ".tabs-holder .product-holder:visible".
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product/review&product_id=209'. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost/index.php?route=product/product/review&product_id=209',          which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://localhost/index.php?route=record/record/captcham'. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost/index.php?route=record/record/captcham', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not  dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen.  In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)
```

After i click on "Buy" button, also add this one:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://localhost//index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

But if i try to open Chrome in terminal with this options:

```
 open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

There no any errors when loading product page, but button still doesnt work.

And also there is a problem with log in to admin panel - i open 'http://localhost/admin/', than enter login/psw (i check it many times - it correct) and in just reload page and ask to enter login/psw again.

Im beginner in web programming and maybe give little information about problem - if that, please tell me what else we need to solve this problem, i will try to find it and write it in comments.
Thanks!

Comment: Check your website output for `Origin` and `Access-Control-*` headers.

Comment: @umka i have this code in httpd.conf: `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>` and also i uncomment `LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so`. Or could you clarify please what are you talk about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the problem - it was this lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L].
```

I have change it to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and it works! It helped to find a solution to the problem of the log in to the admin panel. But I dont understand why on virtual server is everything ok, but doesnt work on local server.